# Multiple operating systems on the same PC and Large Drives

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot, mbr, boot-manager

I've always had multiple OS on my Computer.
Using MBR and Boot managers i was able to do this until now.
But today i've replaced my Pc with a new one that have a large HDD , 5TB.
Reading on internet i've found that using MBR it's not possible to create partitions beyond the 2.2TB , so i can't manage all my drive's space.
So i thought to use GPT/UEFI scheme.
But now i have problems because it seems that the boot managers available on the market ( as far i know ) doesn't support booting from UEFI/GPT .
I've contacted with the TerabyteUnlimited company that has the Bootit boot manager that i've used until now , but they told me the same thing that doesn't support booting from Uefi/GPT.

So what can i do to have multiple OS installed on my pc but also to use all my HDD's space ?

Answer (score 0):

So you need using GPT for your Hard Drive.
And also a boot manager that support booting from GPT/UEFI.
The only boot manager that I've found and support booting from GPT/UEFI is rEFInd.
Take a look here http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/